# Json.net deserializing list gives duplicate items

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have just started using Newtonsoft.Json (Json.net). In my first simple test, I ran into a problem when deserializing generic lists. In my code sample below I serialize an object, containing three types of simple integer lists (property, member var and array).

The resulting json looks fine (the lists are converted into json-arrays). However, when I deserialize the json back to a new object of the same type, all list items are duplicated, expect for the array. I've illustrated that by serializing it a second time.

From searching around, I've read that there may be a "private" backing field to the lists that the deserializer also fills.

So my question is: Is there a (preferably simple) way to avoid duplicate items in following case?

#### Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace JsonSerializeExample
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var data = new SomeData();
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
            Console.WriteLine("First : {0}", json);
            var data2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeData>(json);
            var json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data2);
            Console.WriteLine("Second: {0}", json2);
        }
    }

    public class SomeData
    {
        public string SimpleField;
        public int[] IntArray;
        public IList<int> IntListProperty { get; set; }
        public IList<int> IntListMember;

        public SomeData()
        {
            SimpleField = "Some data";
            IntArray = new[] { 7, 8, 9 };
            IntListProperty = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
            IntListMember = new List<int> { 4, 5, 6 };
        }
    }
}
```

#### Resulting output

```
First : {"SimpleField":"Some data","IntArray":[7,8,9],"IntListMember":[4,5,6],"IntListProperty":[1,2,3]}
Second: {"SimpleField":"Some data","IntArray":[7,8,9],"IntListMember":[4,5,6,4,5,6],"IntListProperty":[1,2,3,1,2,3]}
```

There may be some overlap here with [Json.Net duplicates private list items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615462/json-net-duplicates-private-list-items). However, I think my problem is even simpler, and I still haven't figured it out.

Comment: My example was broken, as the contructor populated the lists. Duh!

Comment: See also: [Repeated serialization and deserialization creates duplicate items](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24835262/10263)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That is because you are adding items in the constructor. A common approach in deserializers when processing a list is basically:

- read the list via the getter

  - if the list is null: create a new list and assign via the property setter, if one
- deserialize each item in turn, and append (`Add`) to the list

this is because most list members **don't have setters**, i.e.

```
public List<Foo> Items {get {...}} // <=== no set
```

Contrast to arrays, which must have a setter to be useful; hence the approach is usually:

- deserialize each item in turn, and append (`Add`) to a temporary list
- convert the list to an array (`ToArray`), and assign via the setter

Some serializers give you options to control this behavior (others don't); and some serializers give you the ability to bypass the constructor completely (others don't).

Comment: Yes, I saw my mistake the second I pressed post :D. But thanks for your answer!

Comment: My example was broken, as the contructor populated the lists. Duh!

Answer (score 27):

I'm pretty sure that this post is not relevant anymore, but for future reference, here a working solution.
Just need to specify that `ObjectCreationHandling` is set to `Replace`, i.e. Always create new objects and not to `Auto` (which is the default) i.e. Reuse existing objects, create new objects when needed.

```
var data = new SomeData(); 
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
Console.WriteLine("First : {0}", json);
var data2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeData>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings() { ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace });
var json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data2);
Console.WriteLine("Second: {0}", json2);
```

Comment: That worked great for me, thanks! But I also need to set "TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto" or it breaks with exception "Could not create an instance of type bla"

Comment: This was very helpful for me! 3 years later and it's still relevant...

Answer (score 10):

I encountered a similar issue with a different root cause.  I was serializing and deserializing a class that looked like this:

```
public class Appointment
{
    public List<AppointmentRevision> Revisions { get; set; }

    public AppointmentRevision CurrentRevision
    {
        get { return Revision.LastOrDefault(); }
    }

    public Appointment()
    {
        Revisions = new List<AppointmentRevision>();
    }
}

public class AppointmentRevision
{
    public List<Attendee> Attendees { get; set; }
}
```

When I serialized this, CurrentRevision was being serialized too.  I'm not sure how, but when it was deserializing it was correctly keeping a single instance of the AppointmentRevision but creating duplicates in the Attendees list.  The solution was to use the JsonIgnore attribute on the CurrentRevision property.

```
public class Appointment
{
    public List<AppointmentRevision> Revisions { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]   
    public AppointmentRevision CurrentRevision
    {
        get { return Revision.LastOrDefault(); }
    }

    public Appointment()
    {
        Revisions = new List<AppointmentRevision>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the exact same issue that was doubling all of my read only properties. This attributed fixed my issue too.

Answer (score 2):

[How to apply ObjectCreationHandling.Replace to selected properties when deserializing JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744236/how-to-apply-objectcreationhandling-replace-to-selected-properties-when-deserial)

Turns out (I'm in 2019), you can set the list items in your constructor as you were doing in your question. I added the ObjectCreationHandling.Replace attribute above my declaration of the list, then serialising should replace anything stored in the list with the JSON.