# JSON.NET deserialize object using all properties in JSON (overriding all initialized in the constructor)

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I have a class with some properties, one of them a list of items. All of them are initialized in the default parameterless constructor of the class. I only want to have to have this constructor that initalizes everything.

This is a case for many of my classes.

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    public ExampleClass()
    {
        this.ListProperty = new List<int> { 1, 2 };
        this.APropertyToBeNull = new TypeA();
        this.BPropertyToBeNull = new TypeB();
    }

    public List<int> ListProperty { get; set; }

    public TypeA APropertyToBeNull { get; set; }

    public TypeB BPropertyToBeNull { get; set; }
}
```

**I create an instance of this class, I set some of the properties to null and I modify the list property to have 2 items**.

```
  var instance = new ExampleClass();
  instance.APropertyToBeNull = null;
  instance.BPropertyToBeNull = null;
  instance.ListProperty = new List<int> { 3 };

  var raw = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(instance);            
  var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExampleClass>(raw, settings);

  Assert.AreEqual(1, deserialized.ListProperty.Count);
  Assert.IsNull(deserialized.APropertyToBeNull);
  Assert.IsNull(deserialized.BPropertyToBeNull);
```

When I deserialize, I don't find a way of getting the item exactly as I serialized it. I got two options:

1. If I set the ObjectCreationHandling to Replace, the list deserializes fine, but the null properties are not null anymore. The constructor initialized everything, the deserialization replaced the list completely but **it did not set the null properties to null**.
2. If I set the ObjectCreationHandling to Auto or Reuse, the null properties are deserialized fine as null, but the list has the items that were initialized in the constructor **plus the items in the JSON**. I only want those in the JSON.

How do I get the exact same item I serialized without removing the initialization of all the properties in the constructor (I still want to have all of them initialized in case a new instance is created).

I have played with all possible settings of the serializer, and I don't find a solution.

As a further constraint, I don't want to add attributes to all of my classes. I have this problem for many of them.

Comment: Difficult to tell what you mean without seeing some code, ideally a MVCE

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: The problem is not Json.Net - it is you violating SRP. The class should only be used for de-/serialization.

Comment: You have tagged this [tag:json.net] but Json.NET does not have a type `JsonTextSerializer`.  May I instead assume use of the [`JsonConvert`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm) class? If so, I made the following [mcve] for reference: https://dotnetfiddle.net/No0QHV

Comment: Looks like `CollectionClearingContractResolver` from [Populate object where objects are reused and arrays are replaced?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42167029/3744182) solves your problem.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/VIzl72 for a working fiddle.  Unless you have some additional problem I'll go ahead and close this as a duplicate.

Comment: Actually, setting `ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace` in `JsonSerializerSettings` works also.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/AgRHNc and [Repeated serialization and deserialization creates duplicate items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24835262/3744182).  So this could be a duplicate of both questions.

Comment: @dbc it looks like the `CollectionClearingContractResolver` solves it, and it's not too slow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `[JsonProperty]` attribute with the `DefaultValueHandling` property.

Given this class:

```
public class Foo
{
    [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate)]
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public List<bool> Baz { get; set; }

    public Foo()
    {
        Bar = "Not Null";
        Baz = new List<bool>
        {
            false
        };
    }
}
```

And this JSON:

```
{ "baz" : [ true ] }
```

This code:

```
string json = "{ \"baz\" : [ true ] }";

var foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace
});

Console.WriteLine(foo.Bar ?? "(null)");
foreach (var b in foo.Baz)
{
    Console.WriteLine(b);
}
```

Will print:

```
(null)
True
```

Meaning the `Bar` string will be overwritten with the value from the JSON, being `null` since it's missing.

Comment: I don't want to add that to all of my classes. I have this problem for many of them