# How to apply ObjectCreationHandling.Replace to selected properties when deserializing JSON?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have a class that contains a `List<Tuple<int, int, int>>` property whose default constructor allocates the list and fills it with some default values, for instance:

```
public class Configuration
{
    public List<Tuple<int, int, int>> MyThreeTuple { get; set; }

    public Configuration()
    {
        MyThreeTuple = new List<Tuple<int, int, int>>();
        MyThreeTuple.Add(new Tuple<int, int, int>(-100, 20, 501));
        MyThreeTuple.Add(new Tuple<int, int, int>(100, 20, 864));
        MyThreeTuple.Add(new Tuple<int, int, int>(500, 20, 1286));
    }
}
```

When I deserialize an instance of this class from JSON using Json.NET, the values from JSON get *added* to the list rather than *replacing* the items in the list, causing the list to have too many values.  A solution to this problem is given in [Json.Net calls property getter during deserialization of list, resulting in duplicate items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25555839/2985796).

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace };
var config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Configuration>(jsonString, settings);
```

This causes Json.NET to allocate fresh instances everything being deserialized.

However, this introduces an additional problem: my class exists in a larger object graph, and some of the types in the graph do not have default constructors.  They are instead constructed by a constructor in the containing class.  If I use `ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace`, Json.NET fails trying to construct instances of these types with the following exception:

```
Unable to find a constructor to use for the type MySpecialType. A class 
should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments
or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute.
```

How can I apply `ObjectCreationHandling.Replace` selectively to certain properties in my object graph, and not others?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your problem, it would greatly help us help you.

Comment: dbc, That was the most beautiful edit I've ever seen on SO.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have a few alternatives to force your list to be replaced rather than reused:

1. You can add an [attribute](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ObjectCreationHandling.htm) to the list property indicating that it should be replaced not reused:

   ```
   public class Configuration
   {
       [JsonProperty(ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace)]
       public List<Tuple<int, int, int>> MyThreeTuple { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. You can use an array instead of a list, as arrays are always replaced.  This might make sense if your list should *always* contain three items and is never resized:

   ```
   public class Configuration
   {
       public Tuple<int, int, int>[] MyThreeTuple { get; set; }

       public Configuration()
       {
           MyThreeTuple = new[]
           {
               new Tuple<int, int, int>(-100, 20, 501),
               new Tuple<int, int, int>(100, 20, 864),
               new Tuple<int, int, int>(500, 20, 1286),
           };
       }
   }
   ```
3. If you don't want your class definitions to have a dependency on Json.NET, you can make a custom [`JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) that clears the list when deserializing:

   ```
   public class ConfigurationConverter : JsonConverter
   {
       public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
       {
           return typeof(Configuration).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
       }

       public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           var config = (existingValue as Configuration ?? (Configuration)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType).DefaultCreator());
           if (config.MyThreeTuple != null)
               config.MyThreeTuple.Clear();
           serializer.Populate(reader, config);
           return config;
       }

       public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

       public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
       }
   }
   ```

   Then use it with the following [`JsonSerializerSettings`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationsettings.htm):

   ```
   var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = new JsonConverter[] { new ConfigurationConverter() } };
   ```
4. If you want *all* list properties to be replaced rather than reused, you can make a custom [`ContractResolver`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver.htm) that does this:

   ```
   public class ListReplacementContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
   {
       // As of 7.0.1, Json.NET suggests using a static instance for "stateless" contract resolvers, for performance reasons.
       // http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm
       // http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver__ctor_1.htm
       // "Use the parameterless constructor and cache instances of the contract resolver within your application for optimal performance."
       static readonly ListReplacementContractResolver instance;

       // Using a static constructor enables fairly lazy initialization.  http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx
       static ListReplacementContractResolver() { instance = new ListReplacementContractResolver(); }

       public static ListReplacementContractResolver Instance { get { return instance; } }

       protected ListReplacementContractResolver() : base() { }

       protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
       {
           var jsonProperty = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
           if (jsonProperty.ObjectCreationHandling == null && jsonProperty.PropertyType.GetListType() != null)
               jsonProperty.ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace;
           return jsonProperty;
       }
   }

   public static class TypeExtensions
   {
       public static Type GetListType(this Type type)
       {
           while (type != null)
           {
               if (type.IsGenericType)
               {
                   var genType = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
                   if (genType == typeof(List<>))
                       return type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
               }
               type = type.BaseType;
           }
           return null;
       }
   }
   ```

   Then use it with the following settings:

   ```
   var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = ListReplacementContractResolver.Instance };
   ```
5. If the collection is get-only (which it is not in this case) see [Clear collections before adding items when populating existing objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35482896/clear-collections-before-adding-items-when-populating-existing-objects).

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks @dbc, just what I needed. My problem was System.Net.Mail.MailAddress, so adding an attribute was never an option. I went with solution 4, a custom ContractResolver. Thanks again!