# Clear collections before adding items when populating existing objects

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have an object which has several collection properties defined with public getter but private setter, In this case `JsonConvert.PopulateObject` adds the deserialized items to these collections leaving the existing items untouched.

I need a behavior when such member collections get cleared before deserialization.

I tried to manually clear the collections in a method marked with the `[OnDeserializing]` attribute.

The problem with that approach is that it will still clear the collections even if the collection property does not exist in the JSON string.

I need a way when only those collections get cleared which are actually defined in the JSON string. Those which are undefined should be kept untouched.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting `ObjectCreationHandling` to `Replace`?  See [Serialization Settings](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationSettings.htm) in the documentation.

Comment: No because as I understand that, it means that it replaces **the collection**, not the items. It would create a new list instance, which is not what I want (that's why the setter is private, no one should mess with the list instance due to databinding, etc.).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, so after some trip to Json.NET sources I found the following solution by inheriting a custom contract resolver from `DefaultContractResolver`.

I needed to override the array contract creation to add a deserialization callback. At this point the callback receives the concrete collection instance, so we can manipulate it (in this case clear it).

As long as I can determine, it is safe to use, but feel free to warn about any drawbacks of this method.

*Note: Am I the only one who feels that this should probably be the default behavior?*

```
public class CollectionClearingContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonArrayContract CreateArrayContract(Type objectType)
    {
        var c = base.CreateArrayContract(objectType);
        c.OnDeserializingCallbacks.Add((obj, streamingContext) =>
        {
            var list = obj as IList;
            if (list != null && !list.IsReadOnly)
                list.Clear();
        });
        return c;
    }
}

...

public class Test {
    public List<int> List { get; private set; }
    public Test() {
        List = new List<int>();
    }
}  

...

var myObj = new Test();
myObj.List.AddRange(new[] {1,2,3});
var listReference = myObj.List;    

JsonConvert.PopulateObject("{ List: [4, 5, 6] }", myObj, 
    new JsonSerializerSettings {
        ContractResolver = new CollectionClearingContractResolver(),
    });

myObj.List.ShouldEqual(listReference); // didn't recreate list
myObj.List.Count.ShouldEqual(3);
myObj.List.SequenceEqual(new[] { 4, 5, 6}).ShouldBeTrue();
```

Comment: I would add a check to see whether `obj` is an array before clearing it, since arrays are read-only.  Or check [`IList.IsReadOnly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.isreadonly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for that matter.

Comment: I'm with you in that I think this should be the default behavior.