# Newtonsoft json has a deserialization bug when class has 'quick' access property for list

Tags: c#, json.net

I have parent class that contains a collection of child POCOs as well as a property that provides quick access to the first member of the collection.  The child POCO types in turn contain another child collection.  When I round-tip the parent using Json.NET, the contents of the first child's collection get duplicated.

What can be done to prevent this?

Minimal reproducible as follows:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace MyApp // Note: actual namespace depends on the project name.
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var parent = new Parent
            {
                Children = new List<Child>
                {
                    new Child
                    {
                       Children = new List<GrandChild>
                        {
                            new GrandChild { Value = "I am a grand child" },
                        }
                    },
                    new Child(),
                }
            };

            var serializedParent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parent);
            var deserializedParent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Parent>(serializedParent);

            // Expected: 1, Actual: 2
            Console.WriteLine(deserializedParent.Children[0].Children.Count);
        }
   }

    public class Parent
    {
         public List<Child> Children { get; set; } = new List<Child>();

         public Child FirstChild => Children.First();
    }

    public class Child
    {
        public List<GrandChild> Children { get; set; } = new List<GrandChild>();
    }

    public class GrandChild
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Demo fiddle with a failing assertion [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YrQeR9).

Comment: What's the exact problem? What's the question? This is just a block of code without any context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that Json.NET will **populate** a get-only property when it is pre-allocated.  In the case of the `FirstChild` you need to avoid this, because, in doing so, Json.NET ends up deserializing the contents of `FirstChild.Children` twice.

In detail, the sequence of events during deserialization is as follows:

1. Since `"Children"` property happens to come first in the JSON, the `Children` array is completely deserialized.
2. At this point, `FirstChild` now returns a `Child` instance rather than throwing a *`System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements`* exception.
3. Json.NET now encounters the `"FirstChild"` property in the JSON, binds it to the `Parent.FirstChild` c# property.  Since it is non-null, it populates the contents, which means that `FirstChild.Children` is populated twice as explained in *[Json.net deserializing list gives duplicate items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13394401)*.

So, what are your workarounds?

**Firstly**, if you don't need `FirstChild` in the JSON, you could simply mark it with `[JsonIgnore]` which will prevent it from being serialized or deserialized:

```
public class Parent
{
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; } = new List<Child>();

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Child FirstChild => Children.First();
}
```

This will also prevent serialization from failing when `Children` is empty.  Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/htI2gW).

**Secondly**, if you must have `FirstChild` present in your JSON, you could attach a `JsonConverter` to the property that, in `ReadJson()`, skips the incoming JSON and simply returns the existing value:

```
public class Parent
{
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; } = new List<Child>();

    [JsonConverter(typeof(SerializeOnlyJsonConverter))]
    public Child FirstChild => Children.First();
    
    public bool ShouldSerializeFirstChild() => Children != null && Children.Count > 0;
}

public class SerializeOnlyJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => throw new NotImplementedException("This converter should only be applied directly to properties");

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) 
    {
        reader.Skip();
        return existingValue;
    }
    
    public override bool CanWrite => false;
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

You will also need to add a [`ShouldSerialize`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/conditionalproperties.htm) method to prevent serializing from failing when `Children` is null or empty.  Or you could fix `FirstChild` to never throw an exception:

```
    public Child FirstChild => Children?.FirstOrDefault();
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9ZNPv5).

**Thirdly**, you could serializing using `GetOnlyContractResolver` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56885301/3744182) by [Pavlo Lissov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7027460/pavlo-lissov) to *[Serialize Property, but Do Not Deserialize Property in Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31731320/3744182)* and apply `[GetOnlyJsonProperty]` to `FirstChild`

```
public class Parent
{
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; } = new List<Child>();

    [GetOnlyJsonProperty]
    public Child FirstChild => Children.First();
    
    public bool ShouldSerializeFirstChild() => Children != null && Children.Count > 0;
}

[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class GetOnlyJsonPropertyAttribute : Attribute
{
}

public class GetOnlyContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    // From this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56885301/3744182
    // By https://stackoverflow.com/users/7027460/pavlo-lissov
    // To https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31731320/serialize-property-but-do-not-deserialize-property-in-json-net
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if (property != null) 
        {
            var attributes = property.AttributeProvider.GetAttributes(typeof(GetOnlyJsonPropertyAttribute), true);
            if (attributes != null && attributes.Count > 0)
                property.ShouldDeserialize = (a) => false;  
        }
        return property;
    }
}
```

And then serialize as follows:

```
IContractResolver resolver = new GetOnlyContractResolver(); // In production code this should be cached statically to improve performance
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = resolver };

var serializedParent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parent, settings);
var deserializedParent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Parent>(serializedParent, settings);

var reserializedParent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deserializedParent, settings);
```

Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/73kWm3).